# How do I fix returning [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

The code below is working perfectly fine, however, when I do `!help test` it returns as `Name... Usage: [object Object]test` I am not sure how to make the bot send the default prefix or the guild's set prefix. **Note:** `${PREFIX}` and `{prefix}` both returns as `[object Object]`. How can I fix this issue?

```
   let prefix;
        try {
            let fetched = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);
            if (fetched == null) {
                prefix = PREFIX
            } else {
                prefix = fetched
            }
            if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix} `)) return;
            if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX} `)) return;
            if(!args[0]) {
               return message.channel.send(`Correct Use: \`${prefix}help <cmd>\``);
            } else if (args[0] == 'test') {
               message.channel.send(`Name... Usage: \`${prefix}test\``);
            }

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    };
```

Comment: prefix isn't a string.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how could I possibly fix it? Kinda dumb with this.

Comment: You need to figure out what `fetched` is. Maybe it has a prefix property but that's just a guess. What I do know is that the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]` and that's what is being interpolated into your string.

Comment: Yea you need to log what fetched is when it doesn't equal null, also what's `PREFIX`?

Comment: I got that working, however when a guild doesn't have a prefix set, it returns as `null`, how can I get the bot to send the default prefix instead?

Comment: You could use the logical OR operator. `null || 'm!'` would return `'m!'`